# Logoff on suspend

Tags: 11.10, suspend

Just recently, my Ubuntu 11.10 laptop presents my with the login screen when resuming from sleep (suspend) mode. So I basically loose any work I had open when I put the computer to sleep. Any idea why or how to fix this?

Comment: Is it the same as [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/904569) on Launchpad?

Comment: The problem has been resolved somehow. I suspect it was some update that did it.

Answer (score 1):

*(OP stated issue resolved)*

Problem resolved. Looks like an automatic update fixed it.